# Edit HTML of navigation menu in wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I face an issue with HTML edit in wordpress theme. I have created a CSS class containing an image and I have created a menu item with this css class. Now I need to have this whole image clickable as a button, which transfers me to another page. I know what to do, but I dont know how.

I need to update following HTML code:

```
<li id="menu-item-306" class="sortimentButton menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-306"> <a href="http://beeweiss.com/sortiment/"></a>Sortiment</li>
```

To this HTML code:

```
<a href="http://beeweiss.com/sortiment/">Sortiment
<li id="menu-item-306" class="sortimentButton menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-306"></li></a>
```

What file do I need to update in wordpress with what in order to make such HTML customization for my menu items?

Comment: Please clarify: have you created any CSS? If so, add that to your post by editing it. The phrase "I have created a CSS class" sounds somewhat misleading. Do you mean "I've added a DOM class to some html elements which I'd like to use to add styling via CSS"? You've shown 2 pieces of html.. but CSS doesn't alter element hierarchy! If you want to open a link on clicking anywhere in your `li`, you have to set an `onclick` handler to it.

Comment: You're proposing to wrap an <li> tag with an <a>, but that is non-standards compliant. https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/lists.html#h-10.2 It seems far simpler to just modify your css declaration than to force WP to generate new html.

Answer (score 1):

Best practice is to create a child theme  ( https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes ). After you create the child theme, you can modify style.css with your desired css.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to update the `functions.php` file to "register" the nav and then include the html+css in the theme directory.

The following links might help:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Navigation_Menus

http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/how-to-add-custom-navigation-menus-in-wordpress-3-0-themes/